# Android Updating an App in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Does anyone know how long it usually takes Google Play to update a new version of the app? Should it be instantaneous?

Comment: takes some time for review and reflect on all Google servers.But not more than couple of hours( atleast in my case).

Comment: I know this post has been dead for ages, but if you download the developer console app for your phone, you get notified when the app goes live(in the sense that it is available, if it is an update or a new app)

Answer (score 1):

Depends, I've 3 apps on the store and sometimes It updates in 30 minutes, sometimes in 2 hours. It Never went after that time tho, so be patient, watch a movie and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my app yesterday, it took approximately 4-5 hours for it to reflect in Play. But the stats in my developer console change very slowly, if at all. Google Play is very slow unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You should give anywhere between an hour to possibly even a day for new applications or updated applications.

The Stats will not reflect immediately. Most likely there are nightly tasks that update your stats just once a day.